# LCD for SLA 3D Printer Resin Curing

Tags: lcd, light, uv, 3d

I'm doing some research on what types of LCD displays can be used to filter and pass UV light for resin curing - specifically in the context of building a DIY 3D SLA printer.

The community commonly uses the Sharp LS055R1SX03 module. Looking through the datasheet, there doesn't seem to be any information pertaining to the characteristics of the device when passing UV wavelengths. Is there something special about this module that allows it to filter/pass UV wavelengths compared to other common LCD displays?

Comment: This may be better on [3D Printing.SE](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone here will be able to answer this. If the UV exposure data is not in a datasheet for the LCD (doubtful), then either this model's UV specs is insider knowledge, or the best result after after trying many of them (more likely.)